# Slow import via osm2pgsql to PostgreSQL database

Tags: openstreetmap, postgresql, linux, osm2pgsql

I try to import berlin.osm (33Mb) into the PostgreSQL database 9.1 via osm2pgsql. My desktop is mem 2Gb,proc 2Ghz,hdd 60Gb, RHEL6u2x64. This process is so slowly in particular when I'm going over pending ways. I see this:

*osm2pgsql SVN version 0.80.0 (32bit id space)*

```
osm2pgsql -M -d berlin -s -S "/usr/share/osm2pgsql/default.style" -U "postgres" -W -H "localhost" -P 5432 "/opt/maps/berlin/berlin.osm.bz2"
```

```
Processing: Node(1644k 49.8k/s) Way(304k 12.17k/s) Relation(6337 52.37/s)  parse time: 179s

Node stats: total(1644720), max(1968785138) in 33s
Way stats: total(304296), max(186177757) in 25s
Relation stats: total(6337), max(2504060) in 121s
Committing transaction for planet_osm_point
Committing transaction for planet_osm_line
Committing transaction for planet_osm_polygon
Committing transaction for planet_osm_roads

Going over pending ways

Using 1 helper-processes
processing way (10k) at 0.11k/s
processing way (195k) at 0.11k/s
All child processes exited

Pending ways took 1719s at a rate of 114.01/s
Committing transaction for planet_osm_point
Committing transaction for planet_osm_line
Committing transaction for planet_osm_polygon
Committing transaction for planet_osm_roads

Going over pending relations

Using 1 helper-processes

All child processes exited

Committing transaction for planet_osm_point
Committing transaction for planet_osm_line
Committing transaction for planet_osm_polygon
Committing transaction for planet_osm_roads
Sorting data and creating indexes for planet_osm_point
Sorting data and creating indexes for planet_osm_line
Sorting data and creating indexes for planet_osm_polygon
node cache: stored: 1644720(100.00%), storage efficiency: 66.93% (dense blocks: 60, sparse nodes: 1597241), hit rate: 100.00%
Sorting data and creating indexes for planet_osm_roads
Stopping table: planet_osm_ways
Building index on table: planet_osm_ways (fastupdate=off)
Stopping table: planet_osm_nodes
Stopping table: planet_osm_rels
Building index on table: planet_osm_rels (fastupdate=off)
Stopped table: planet_osm_nodes in 0s
Stopped table: planet_osm_rels in 1s
Indexes on  planet_osm_roads created  in 5s
Completed planet_osm_roads
Indexes on  planet_osm_line created  in 21s
Completed planet_osm_line
Indexes on  planet_osm_point created  in 26s
Completed planet_osm_point
Stopped table: planet_osm_ways in 31s
Indexes on  planet_osm_polygon created  in 31s
Completed planet_osm_polygon
```

*Osm2pgsql took **1931s** overall*

I used the next parameters in my postgresql.conf :

```
shared_buffers=512Mb
temp_buffers=16Mb
work_mem=64Mb
maintenance_work_mem=128Mb
```

When I checked it on the Windows desktop it acceptable worked, but if I started it on my Linux system I have a problems with a import perfomance. What should I do that can fix it?

Answer (score 3):

From the manual:

> osm2pgsql relies much on its node cache during import. If the nodes do
>   not fit into the cache it needs to do database lookups which slow down
>   the process. Use enough cache so all nodes are cached. -C 12000 seems
>   to do the job, even if that means you have to configure more swap
>   space.

Try to use -C 'somethingbig'

[See the wiki](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osm2pgsql)

If you want to try and build this executable yourself, just clone the github code and check the README file, it states somewhere:

```
On most Unix-like systems the program can be compiled by
running './autogen.sh && ./configure && make'.
```

So if you have all the libs/reqs fulfilled you'll be building an executable that works.

Comment: Thanx, Glenn for your reply but I think it is the 0.80 version troubles. Because when I used osm2pgsql v0.80 on Windows server I got the same inconvenience: 
processing way at 0.65k/s

Comment: Any ideas where the problem could be or how to debug this?

Comment: Have you tried a -C  version of your command?  I mean, no offense, but trying to see if it makes a difference costs no effort at all, less than what it takes for me to type this comment.  It's recommended anyway to use it, so why not test this first ?

Comment: of course I tested it and the increment was small. e.g. the processing way has become 0,65k/s instead of 0,11k/s and my memory is quickly filled, when I'm going over pending ways. If I use the osm2pgsql version 0,69 the processing way works fine, relatively quickly.

Comment: Also is there rpm of osm2pgsql 0.69 or 0.70 for EL6? I can't find out it in EPEL repositiry(( due to I can't tested it with old versions on RHEL.

Comment: exuse me what exactly should I copy and execute? Unfortunatelly I'm not perl specialist)

Comment: I don't use RPM's but in my flavor of linux it's under '/usr/bin/osm2pgsql', you don't really need anything else.  You can get it [here](https://github.com/openstreetmap/osm2pgsql)  It seems I'm not correct about it being perl, It's an ELF executable written in C, somehow the perl fact got stuck in my mind.  But that doesn't really change the fact it's the only thing you should need.

Comment: Thanx Glen for your explains. Could you please let me an example how to you start it via gcc or which executable file (a sequence) should I use it? if you don't mind))

Comment: I put the info in the answer to move it away from comments.

Comment: I meant what should I the executable file start?

Comment: I don't know how to build this on windows, sorry.  I gave you the linux instructions, I forgot about windows being the problematic platform.  I never use windows...

Comment: Ok! I tested it on the red hat linux and I've just wanted to know how to start the osm2pgsql process. e.g. when I used osm2pgsql via rpm I imported the data via a compiling file "osm2pgsql -keys", but now I see a group of *.h,*.c files in osm2pgsql folder, which scrypt should I use for the import starting?

Comment: If you built the executable, you can install it by doing a `make install`. The files you mention is source code and source headers which are used to build it and after that do not serve a purpose.  After that, just use it like you used to do it, there should be no difference

Comment: Thank you for this comment. My osm2pgsql was working with 40MB of cache LOL. Need to import all the nodes again but I'm hoping Ways won't chug along at 0.7k/s

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this issue today. Turns out I have to add `--slim` flag.

From [OSM wiki page](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osm2pgsql#Mac_OS_X):

> **Slim mode**
>
> osm2pgsql has two main modes of running - normal and slim mode.
>
> **It is highly recommended to run osm2pgsql in slim mode**. Some important
> features (including incremental updates (planet diffs, the initial
> load to populate the track tables and proper evaluation of
> multipolygons) only work in slim mode.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a very specific answer, but I had a problem with `osm2pgsql` on Windows when attempting to important an entire country into postgres about 6 months ago. After trying this and letting it run for a long time (a day or two) I would get an either an error about memory, or a problem with an aspect of the network. It worked fine on smaller extracts (1 or 2 square kilometers) but using identical settings I could not load a larger extract and eventually gave up.

An alternative approach to get the raw data in another form is to use the free service from [weogeo](http://www.weogeo.com/) which enables you to trace the area on a map that you want data for, and download it via their service.